# Split maild id from paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to split a mail id which contains `@tango.com` from a paragraph.I have different scenarios,email always starts with `SMTP`.which may available anywhere at paragraph.

```
SMTP:abc.Savage@tango.com^smtp:abc.Savage@bcc.com^SIP:abc.Savage@blity.com^x500:/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange tango Group (FYDIB6783SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=292256788979d40d199877fbb4970b51d-Katrina Sav^X400:C=US;A= ;P=abc Concepts;O=KCI;S=Savage;G=Katrina;^smtp:xxx@i1.com^smtp:xxx@kci-bruto.com




smtp:abc.Savage@bcc.com^SIP:abc.Savage@blity.com^x500:SMTP:abc.Savage@tango.com^/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange tango Group (FYDIB6783SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=292256788979d40d199877fbb4970b51d-Katrina Sav^X400:C=US;A= ;P=abc Concepts;O=KCI;S=Savage;G=Katrina;^smtp:xxx@i1.com^smtp:xxx@kci-bruto.com



smtp:abc.Savage@bcc.com^SIP:abc.Savage@blity.com^x500:SMTP:abc.Savage@tango.com^/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange tango Group (FYDIB6783SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=292256788979d40d199877fbb4970b51d-Katrina Sav^X400:C=US;A= ;P=abc Concepts;O=KCI;S=Savage;G=Katrina;^smtp:xxx@i1.com^smtp:xxx@kci-bruto.com^SMTP:abc.Savage@tango.com
```

I hope we can use this regex

```
text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
```

But here I have different mail ids,I want only the mail id which ends with `@tango.com`.

How can I split the email which contains `@tango.com` separately??

Comment: When you say "split" do you mean you are trying to extract the email address?

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var re = /\s*(SMTP|smtp)\:([a-zA-Z\.\_]+)\@tango\.com/g;
var s = 'uibniui SMTP:jnj@tango.com bbuybuy iub SMTP:ghbh@google.com SMTP:hnj.jnj@tango.com ';
var m;
var ids = Array();
do {
    m = re.exec(s);
    if (m) {
        ids.push( m[2]+'@tango.com');
    }
} while (m);

console.log(ids);
```